# delete duplicate rows matching with other table

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables

```
  Table A                        Table B
  --------                      ---------

  a  b  c                       a  b  c
  a  b  c                       a  b  c
  a  b  c                       a  b  c
  e  f  g                       a  b  c
  h  i  j                       e  f  g
  k  l  m                       k  l  m
                                k  l  m
                                x  y  z
                                s  t  u
                                a  b  c
                                a  b  c
```

Now i want to remove rows in Table B matching on column 1, 2 and 3 with table A where the count of each duplicate row in Table B should be less than or equal to table A.

So the output should be

```
  Table A                        Table B
  --------                      ---------

  a  b  c                       a  b  c
  a  b  c                       a  b  c
  a  b  c                       a  b  c
  e  f  g                       e  f  g
  h  i  j                       k  l  m
  k  l  m                       x  y  z                                                                      
                                s  t  u
```

I have tried using inner join and intersect but failed to get the desired result.

Comment: can you paste the structure of the table? it will be easier to help you, you can use sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
DELETE FROM tableB
WHERE ctid IN (
   SELECT BB.ctid
   FROM (
     SELECT a, b, c, count(*) cnt
     FROM tablea
     GROUP BY a, b, c
   ) AA
   JOIN (
     SELECT ctid, 
            a, b, c, 
            row_number() over (partition by a,b,c) cnt
     FROM tableb
   ) BB
   ON AA.a = BB.a
      AND AA.b = BB.b
      AND AA.c = BB.c
      AND AA.cnt < BB.cnt
)
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/73e99/1

Answer (score -2):

I think if table isn't big the simply way is to delete all rows from TableB which exist in TableA and then insert TableA into TableB. Another ways IMHO are required at least a primary key in TableB.

```
DELETE FROM TableB 
            WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableA 
                                   WHERE C1=TableA.C1 
                                         AND C2=TableA.C2 
                                         AND C3=TableA.C3) ;

INSERT INTO TableB SELECT * FROM TableA;
```

Comment: he/she wants to keep the duplicates in tableB as long as they're present in tableA

Comment: @Leo But if rows are duplicates and THERE IS NO primary key how you can decide which on you should delete?

Comment: he/she does not want to remove duplicates from a table, he/she wants to remove rows from one table that are not present in another

Comment: and also there's that strange count thing

Comment: I am sorry, you're right. Can you do some minimal edit in your answer do I can remove the downvote?